# Add Documentation is disabled in Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, documentation, xcode8

Why "Add Documentation" is disabled in Xcode 8.2? How can I enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the making it enable you need to select code first like following gif and you can add documentation based on selection.

[image]

Comment: I have followed exactly your steps, but this is not working in my case, Am I missing something else in settings etc ? :(

Comment: try to restart xcode. might be issue solve. but steps in that only

Comment: This is working fine incase I am creating a new project in swift.

Comment: yes, it started working after restarting XCode. thanks!

Comment: Same issue for me. No change after restarting Xcode. This is with Xcode 9.3

Comment: as i mention you should select what code you want to documented

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to appear randomly for myself as well. The only surefire way I've found to re-enable it is to run

`sudo /usr/libexec/xpccachectl`

in the terminal and restart my computer.

Answer (score 0):

It's ridiculous that it still happens even with Xcode 10.1. And it have a ridiculous solution:

Exit Xcode, then rename `Xcode.app` to something else like `Xcode1.app`, then back to `Xcode.app`. For Appstore version you will be asked for admin password.